# How can i create and auto install of other open source software such as openvpn and snort using kickstart?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, kickstart

I'm new to kick start and i would like to know how i can create an auto install of open source software such as open vpn and Snort using kick start.

Can this be done by post  scripting the file?
or using the .deb files?

Answer (score 1):

## Multiple Computer installation using Kickstart

This instruction follows the [help.ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06.html) instructions:

- Generate a Kickstart file

  ```
  sudo update
  sudo apt install system-config-kickstart
  ```

  Then run

  ```
  system-config-kickstart&
  ```
- Config installer

  The kickstarter should open. Enter your configuration, user/root, partitions, 
  etc.On the %post section you can add your apt install commands.

[image]

Save your config file.

(note the sudo infront of the apt command is an error! use apt without sudo)

- Now make a kernel modification as described on the manual page

> To make the installer use a Kickstart file downloaded from a web or FTP server, add ks=http://url/to/ks.cfg or ks=ftp://url/to/ks.cfg
>   respectively to the kernel boot parameters. This requires the
>   installer to be able to set up the network via DHCP on the first
>   connected interface without asking any questions; you may also need to
>   add ksdevice=eth1 or similar if the installer fails to determine the
>   correct interface automatically.
>
> Similarly, to make the installer use a Kickstart file on an NFS
>   server, add ks=nfs:server:/path/to/ks.cfg to the kernel boot
>   parameters. The method supported by Anaconda of adding a plain "ks"
>   boot parameter to work out the location of the Kickstart file from a
>   DHCP response is not yet supported by the Ubuntu installer.
>
> To place a Kickstart file on a CD, you would need to remaster the ISO
>   image to include your Kickstart file, and add ks=cdrom:/path/to/ks.cfg
>   to the kernel boot parameters. See the manual page for mkisofs for
>   details. Alternatively, put the Kickstart file on a floppy, and add
>   ks=floppy:/path/to/ks.cfg to the kernel boot parameters.

Don't forget to add the canonical, universe ppas before installing !

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question about automating these install steps.